# Dapper What is wrong?

Tags: dapper

I have this code should be working but this is throwing an exception Must declare variable scalar

```
 public async Task<Job> GetJobByUd(Guid jobId)
    {
        var sql = "select * from dbo.Jobs where JobId = @jobId;";
        using (DbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            var job = await db.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<Job>(sql, new {jobId});
            return job;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does `select * from dbo.Jobs where JobId = ?;` work? Is `JobId` a unique field?

Comment: Please update the description of the problem to better reflect what exactly you need help with. Also, it would be helpful if you included an exception stacktrace.

Comment: the column name is JobId  it is SQL server, I am declaring the variable as @jobId

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, it should work.

```
public async Task<Job> GetJobByUd(Guid jobId)
    {
        var sql = "select * from dbo.Jobs where JobId = @jobId;";
        using (DbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            var job = await db.QueryAsync<Job>(sql, new {jobId = jobId}).FirstOrDefault();
            return job;
        }

    }
```